# which is better/how they differ? independent t-test or simple logistic regression?

Tags: regression, t-test

As a beginner in stats, i am wondering do simple logistic regression do what independent t-test does? and if yes, why do we still do t-test ?

e.g. If there is a binary variable (e.g. smokers to non-smoking )  and a continuous variable (e.g. age)

I can use t-test to test the mean difference between the 2 groups

I can use simple logistic regression and consider smoking as outcome and age as predictor

I think i can also use bisereal correlation ??

are they different ?

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 1):

All three procedures can yield, if this is of interest, *p*-values telling the probability that results as far or farther from the usual null hypothesis would occur if chance alone were responsible.  Beyond that, each procedure will give a different type of potentially useful information:

- *Point*-biserial correlation will yield a coefficient ranging from -1 to 1, 
  summarizing (in somewhat abstract or scale-free terms) the degree of
  connection between age and smoking status.  (Note that the lesser-used "biserial correlation" works somewhat differently:  see [explanation](http://ncss.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Point-Biserial_and_Biserial_Correlations.pdf)).
- *T*-testing will
     describe the mean age difference between smokers and non-smokers in
     terms of the standard error of such a difference.
- Logistic
     regression will yield the difference in (the odds of being a        smoker) that is associated with each unit (presumably year) 
     difference in age.  Logistic regression can also be used to generate a probability that each person is a smoker, based on age.

Thus in a given research situation these procedures may well turn out to be complementary.